# How to display results of Smartsearch

Tags: search, kentico

I'm creating a webpart that uses the SearchHelper to get smart search results based on the search paramaters to display in a live search via Ajax.

I am looking for a way to display the results using the dataset that

```
SearchHelper.Search(SearchParameters)
```

returns in the same manner that the SearchResults webparts work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok never mind, found the answer. The answer is to just use the BasicRepeater.

```
var results = SearchHelper.Search(sp);
BasicRepeater br = new BasicRepeater();
br.DataSource = results;
br.ItemTemplate = CMSDataProperties.LoadTransformation(this, CMS.Root.SmartSearchResults", false);
```